# Plot set of point in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to plot set of test point VS point being tested with Python. I tried several codes and I couldn't figure it out.

```
train_pts2 = {
   "N": [(0.125,0.11), (0.375,0.21), (0.625,0.31), (0,0.01), (0.375,0.50), (0.80,0)],
   "Y": [(0.075,0.38), (0.5,0.22), (1,0.41), (0.70,1),(0.325,0.65), (0.70,0.61)],
   "TBD": [(0.70,0.61)]
   }
```

So the plot will be scatter plot that tells whether pLoan belongs to N or Y

something like

[image]

Comment: Did you already have a look at the scatter plots from matplotlib? http://matplotlib.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with the `matplotlib` library in python with the `scatter()` function

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

train_pts2 = {
   "N": [(0.125,0.11), (0.375,0.21), (0.625,0.31), (0,0.01), (0.375,0.50), (0.80,0)],
   "Y": [(0.075,0.38), (0.5,0.22), (1,0.41), (0.70,1),(0.325,0.65), (0.70,0.61)],
   "TBD": [(0.70,0.61)]
   }

colors = {
    "N" : "orange",
    "Y" : "blue",
    "TBD" : "green"
}

for label in ["N", "Y", "TBD"]:
    x = [item[0] for item in train_pts2[label]]
    y = [item[1] for item in train_pts2[label]]
    plt.scatter(x, y, c=colors[label], label=label)

plt.xlabel("Age of Loan")
plt.ylabel("Loan Amount")
plt.xlim(xmin=0)
plt.ylim(ymin=0)
plt.grid(True)
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.)
plt.show()
```

[image: Matplotlib Scatter Example]

For more information, you can reach the [scatter_demo.py](https://matplotlib.org/examples/shapes_and_collections/scatter_demo.html#shapes-and-collections-example-code-scatter-demo-py) example.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks, but not close to the plot I provided.
also the point   pLoan = (0.70,0.61) is not part of the testSet.
I am trying to determine point (0.70 , 0.61 ) on the plot but I don't see it